# jade markup highlighting inside a template in WebStorm

Tags: syntax-highlighting, pug, webstorm

I use webstorm to work with jade. It works just fine, but when I make a template for knockoutjs:

```
script(type="text/html", id="my_template-id")
   jade syntax here
```

So jade inside such template is not highlighted properly. How do I make WebStorm understand, that this is a jade too?

Comment: Hmm... not sure I follow you... Is your template defined in .jade file? the syntax above 'jade syntax here' looks like jade syntax as well... Note that syntax highlighting inside script tag in jade is currently disabled - see [this ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2137)

Comment: Yes, my markup is inside a jade file. And how do I enable syntax highlighting inside a script tag?

Comment: there is no way to do this. See the reference in my previous comment

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But interesting, is there a workaround. I understand, that I can't have highlight inside a webstorm if I use a script tag. But what if I put it in a separate file and make some custom script assemble my file? I mean I write things inside a jade file, in a special directory, that would be processes and put inside a script tag with corresponding id. If would work, so I'm interested if anyone did anything similiar.

Comment: well, jade supports combining several jade files into one. So you can have ' script(type="text/html", id="my_template-id")
    include myscript ' in main.jade and other stuff (code within script tag) in included myscript.jade... But note that javascript code will still appear without syntax highlighting, even not within script tag :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue, please vote for it:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8967

Comment: [A workaround was suggested as an edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6862450)

Answer (score 0):

The issue tracker claims this to be fixed but it is not. 
Here is a workaround (mixin must come before script):

```
mixin testTemplate
    span(ng-click="doSomething()") click me
    h1 Markup here is working

script(type="text/ng-template", id="template.html")
    +testTemplate()
```